# How can I bind Objective-C++ in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, objective-c++, xamarin.ios-binding

I want to bind an Objective-C++ library in Xamarin. Is this possible? If so, how do I need to declare the namespace those methods are in and what do I put in the `Export` tags?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking to a C++ native library in MonoTouch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245616/linking-to-a-c-native-library-in-monotouch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a very detailed documentation on Objective-C subject here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/

You can refer this answer for the Obj-C++ bindings

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5249007/85606

Comment: So I need to make an Objective-C wrapper for the library, where I simply forward the methods to Objective-C++? And then bind that?

Comment: I did provide a wrapper, but I wrapped it so that I had a `UIViewController` that I can subclass in Xamarin code and simply override a few variables. It does not include all functionality the library provides, only the functionality I needed right now. I can extend the wrapper when I need more of the library.